# Is it possible to create a Data Explorer query that returns questions from users who have more answers than questions?

Tags: support, data-explorer, users

I've found a query that returns questions from users with a certain minimum reputation:

```
select top 20 p.id as [Post Link], p.score, p.viewcount, p.answercount, p.tags,
  u.reputation
from posts p, users u 
where p.owneruserid = u.id
  and u.reputation >= 1000
  and p.deletiondate is null
  and p.tags like '%python%'
order by p.creationdate desc
```

but I'd like to further filter the resultset by users who have answered more questions than they have asked - or alternatively, have a minimum reputation from answers only. Is this possible?

Comment: Here's a starting point for you: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1160991 ... you now only need to join the users DB to filter the reputation or to get a handy link to each user profile.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You forgot duct tape.

Comment: @connectyourcharger: I'll use that one next time (I rotate the third term around.  Last time I think it was donuts).

Comment: @connectyourcharger FYI, if you're interested in duct tape, you may wish to check out the "Red Green Show", e.g., as described in [The star of 'The Red Green Show' says farewell with duct tape firmly in hand](https://www.azcentral.com/story/entertainment/arts/2019/04/18/red-green-aka-steve-smith-bids-farewell-tour-plays-phoenix/3501960002/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, [here you go](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1161092). I'm not sure if this is the most performant way, but I've added some code to calculate the number of answers and questions with the `cross apply` and `outer apply` operators:

```sql
cross apply (
  select count(*) as value
    from posts
    where owneruserid = u.id
      and posttypeid = 2
) answers
cross apply (
  select count(*) as value
    from posts
    where owneruserid = u.id
      and posttypeid = 1
) questions
```

so that I can compare them later:

```
and answers.value > questions.value
```

(Oh, I also removed the filter on `DeletionDate`, since deleted posts never show up in that table.)

Comment: I expect a two column projection with `sum(case when posttypeid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) Q, sum(case when posttypeid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) A` to perform better.

Comment: Probably, but [this query](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/91b9346b33ec89f2ec0544cba8069e06) times out and I *detest* having to specify the projected columns twice (why doesn't SQL understand `GROUP BY p.*, u.*`?)

Comment: maybe inner join on posttags and tags to get those python tags? That should get rid of a full table scan over posts(withdeleted)

Comment: Sure, but my original query doesn't need it... I went for the option that took the least amount of effort to type and so far I'm happy with it :)

Comment: Does the cross apply work for users that have either no answers or questions?

Comment: @dfhwze it should; `select count(*)` would then return 0.