# Strange overlapping post-layout and sidebar

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, responsive-design

I've noticed this issue on a handful of other communities, but making the browser window narrow (mine is 1080x960) makes the `.post-layout` and `#sidebar` elements overlap. Maybe something to do with the grid CSS? The `#mainbar` element seems to be the correct width and changing the `.post-layout`'s `overflow-x` to `auto` seems to "fix" it

From retrocomputing:

[image]

From this post, because we are meta after all:

[image]

Specs:

- Google Chrome Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: Confirmed, FF mobile (Desktop mode). Started ~20 minutes ago.

Comment: Confirmed: Windows 10 (version 1903), monitor resolution 1280×1024 (recommended), Google Chrome the same as OP.

Comment: It just started happening for me in Firefox for iOS (uses Safari's web engine) here and on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.

Comment: Confirmed, Chrome, OS X, 2560 x 1600

Comment: Thanks for reporting! We've got people looking into it. It sounds like CSS is being temperamental... who would have thought!

Comment: @dalearn "end of the day" is relative. We've got people all over the <strike>country</strike> world. It's currently only 1 pm on the west coast.

Comment: This isn’t CSS being temperamental… This is just a regular old bug, caused by incorrect styles. It’s wrong in pretty much every browser.  You need to set the minimum width. See, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/43312314

Comment: @CodyGray Though you're absolutely right, it seems odd that people are seeing the bug all at once.

Comment: @connectyourcharger from a CSS perspective it's not really a bug, it happens as expected due to a default behavior defined in CSS grid.You simply need to know it to correctly write the CSS.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Technically you're correct, but it's a bug on the grounds that the style is unintended, and we'll just leave it at that.

Comment: @connectyourcharger That’s not odd, either. The dev team obviously just deployed an update to their CSS, which contained a bug. I know, it sounds weird, because if you’re like me, you don’t test in production. But, different strokes for different folks.

Comment: @CodyGray Who tests in prod on a Wednesday? That's two days early!

Comment: @CodyGray They obviously [forgot their white chocolate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339487/is-it-possible-to-create-a-data-explorer-query-that-returns-questions-from-users#comment1133357_339487) to tie it all together.

Comment: Same issue here. I'm on FF 69.0 (win 7) with 1080p in landscape. Going bigger (acrossed three 1080p screens) yields same with more wasted white space next to the columns. Going half-width makes the sidebar invisible so usable, though the text still extends outside the central column, and I have to scroll back and forth to read the text.

Comment: At least for once it's not just a specific browser, version, os etc. CSS is acting consistently.

Comment: This was also reported on meta.stackoverflow and [reported there as fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391884).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Answered by @aaron-shekey [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391884/3903479):

> Thanks for reporting this! We deleted a ton of IE-specific CSS and there was some complicated Less logic causing this bug that we didn’t catch in our local environment. This should now be fixed.
>
> Folks, remember, I’m a person. I’m working hard on improving our codebase every day. Some days there will be visual regressions. I’m sure you’ve shipped some.

Response was written about an hour after I posted my question.

Answer (score 6):

Just for completeness experiencing this on mobile (iPhone XR).

[image]

As you can see the question layout is completely cropped to the right and the viewport does not allow you to resize even if you force desktop mode (tested in Google Chrome iOS).

Comment: Oh wow it's significantly worse on mobile

Comment: It’s unusable in it’s current form.

Comment: Can confirm it's working as expected now, the question viewport fits correctly.

Answer (score 4):

I'm facing the same bug. It is a problem for the 9:16 aspect ratio, which is very popular since it's a standard 16:9 monitor turned vertically.

(Sorry if this is more of a comment, I don't have enough rep to comment)

Comment: I think you can still upvote the post, even if the points aren't shown publicly it would act as a confirmation

Comment: @GammaGames You need 15 reputation to upvote, so that's not an option for John.

Comment: @Glorfindel: And, now that they have 31 reputation, it is.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/69289)

Comment: @Sean thanks to [this awesome feature, no one asked for](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/)

Comment: @Sean Sorry for the commotion, I know it's moot now anyway. But since Meta is the official bug-reporting location and since the only thing a no-rep user can do is post questions and answers, it does put someone new to Meta between a rock and a hard place when it comes to engaging with bug reporting. If I have something small but possibly helpful to add to an existing report - like the aspect ratio it affects - I don't have a good place to put that as a new Meta user.

Answer (score 2):

[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

I was getting what I think is the same issue at [Find minimum number of polygons connecting two points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/343981/find-minimum-number-of-polygons-connecting-two-points) when using Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0 on Windows 10 for Workstations:

[image]

However, the issue seems to have now been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed on Chrome 78 (Windows). I'm also going to add another screenshot I think is a bit of an eyesore:

[image: screenshot of unformatted code blocks]

Runnable code blocks don't line-break at *all*, which creates some very long horizontal scroll distances. [Here's a long example from the Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/325431/).

Comment: Your answer is a few seconds too late, the issue seemed to be fixed now :P

Comment: @Tom You're kidding. What happened to 6-8 weeks?!?!

Comment: No worries, someone will break it again ;D

Comment: @Tom It's been fixed for over a half-hour now for me, I think we just have to wait for caches to expire for the fix to get out there. Especially painful for mobile, they love to hold onto stuff

Comment: @GammaGames -- Not fixed.  I just fired up my Macbook a half hour ago and was greeted with this abomination, which wasn't there six hours ago.

Comment: @barbarabeeton it's being [reported as fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391884/3903479) and it is fixed for me, does clearing your cache completely fix it? Maybe their servers aren't all updated yet, though I don't know why it would take so long to spread across

Comment: @GammaGames -- It's still corrupted.  Have cleared cache, logged off, shut down, and logged back on, and it's not fixed yet.  I first logged on *after* you reported it "fixed", after having been away for about five hours, when it was still normal.  I'll check again in the morning.  Thanks.

Comment: @GammaGames -- I just realized that what I'm seeing is not exactly what is reported, but is a different corruption.  There is no overlap, but the up/down arrows and score are, instead of being off to the left-hand side, centered within the text area at the top, occupying about a vertical inch of otherwise empty space.  So I guess this is a (botched) consequence of the "fix".  I'll see what the situation is in the morning, and if it's still flaky, post a new question.

Comment: @barbarabeeton is your device updated? I see that if I completely turn off the `display: grid` rule on the `.post-layout` element

Comment: @GammaGames -- Unfortunately, my Macbook is too old to be fully updated.  I expect to be replacing it soon, so I guess I'll just have to live with what's there.  At least, nothing is overprinted or cut off; if the only real loss is wasted space, it's not as bad as it could be.  Thanks for hints.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I saw the same "up/down arrows" problem like you on the main browser I use (an ancient version of firefox 43.*) which doesn't seem to understand "display: grid", if I change it to "display: inline-flex", it works. you may try update your browser to a version that understand "display: grid" to see whether you can get rid the problem.