# Content running off page on responsive version

Tags: bug, responsive-design

On mobile I browse the responsive design. It usually works well, except today:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange overlapping post-layout and sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339651/strange-overlapping-post-layout-and-sidebar) (not frist: you were a few seconds too late)

Comment: Yes @CodyGray, noticed it when I posted my post.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem not only on mobile but also on desktop sites. The right rail overlaps the main content area when viewing questions and answers. Like this:

[image]